# How to separate buttons (In terms of functionality)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make an upvote function on my website, and it basically works. However, all the Upvoting buttons link to the same thing.

I have something like this:

```
<th width = 50%>
    MAUDE BONNEY
    <br><br>
    <div class="box">
        <label for="qty">
            <abbr title="Quantity">Up Vote!</abbr>
        </label>
        <input id="qty" value="0" />
        <button id="down" onclick="modify_qty(-1)">-1</button>
        <button id="up" onclick="modify_qty(1)">+1</button>
</th>
```

and here's my javascript (I have a css but I don't think its important)

```
function modify_qty(val) {
    var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    var new_qty = parseInt(qty,10) + val;

    document.getElementById('qty').value = new_qty;
    return new_qty;
}
```

How do I make all the buttons not connected? When you press one of the +1 or -1 buttons it only effects one of the counters. How do I make them all individuals?

Comment: Do you use the ID `qty` more than once? IDs **must** be unique

Comment: The html you gave as an example is lacking a `</div>` element, as well as only representing one table header element. In order for this to be answerable, you would need to include more of the table itself, at least enough to reproduce the issue of the buttons being connected, as it seems there is no issue with one of these table elements - there are however several issues with trying to use this approach with multiple voting sections on the same page. Please fix your html and give a slightly broader example of the elements in order for this question to be answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current way of labeling(id), you can't really link each button to a specific count without having each button having a different id. You could do it with php, but you need to download a server and things like that. So for now, there isn't really an easy way for you to link each button to a specific count.

Comment: I solved it by creating a new function (just renaming them) for each voting button. It wasn't recognizing them as different buttons, thanks for the help!